# making array of file by lines using vbs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vbscript

I am new to vbs and have a question. I have a js file of variables that says var varname = "variable"; on each line. I am wanting to make an array of everything inside of the quotes in vbs. I do not know how to make this work.

```
' Sample vbs
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("path", ForReading)

Const ForReading = 1

Dim arrFileLines()
i = 0
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
Redim Preserve arrFileLines(i)
arrFileLines(i) = objFile.ReadLine
i = i + 1
Loop
objFile.Close

'Then you can iterate it like this
For Each strLine in arrFileLines
leftquote = InStr(strLine,"""")
rightquote = InStrRev(strLine,"""")
str=CStr(strLine)
leng = rightquote-leftquote
WScript.Echo Mid(str,leftquote+1,leng)


Next
```

Here is the js

```
// Sample js
var a = new Array();
a[0] = "1";
a[1] = "2";
a[2] = "3";
a[3] = "4";
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to use VBS to process a text file (JS in this case) and output a different text file? _"Here is the js"_ - Is that your desired _output?_ Please show both input and output and make it clear which is which.

Comment: No, I want to create an array in the vbs that retrieves the variables from the js file listed.

Comment: OK, so the `var varname = "variable";` example from the second sentence in your question is not really what the JS file contains? Really the file looks like the sample at the end of your question? Will the JS variable always be called `a`, or...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a RegExp to extract the data between double quotes on the whole of the file's content. In code:

```
  Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
  Dim reCut : Set reCut = New RegExp
  reCut.Global = True
  reCut.Pattern = """([^""]+)"""
  Dim sAll : sAll = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\sample.js").ReadAll()
  WScript.Echo sAll
  Dim oMTS : Set oMTS = reCut.Execute(sAll)
  If 0 = oMTS.Count Then
     WScript.Echo "parse error"
  Else
     ReDim aAll(oMTS.Count - 1)
     Dim i
     For i = 0 To UBound(aAll)
         aAll(i) = oMTS(i).SubMatches(0) ' or: aAll(i) = CStr(oMTS(i).SubMatches(0))
     Next
     WScript.Echo Join(aAll, ", ")
  End If
```

output:

```
// Sample js
var a = new Array();
a[0] = "1";
a[1] = "2";
a[2] = "3";
a[3] = "4";

1, 2, 3, 4
```

This approach avoids wasting your and your computer's resources on

1. creating a dispensable array of lines (you don't need access a line j when you process line i)
2. rolling your own 'parser'